# Spark streaming processes RDDs one by one?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote a `Spark Streaming` program by `pyspark`.

It receives live input text stream by `socketTextStream` and does some transformations and saves it as `csv` file by `saveAsTextFile`. `Spark streaming` window operation is not used and no previous data is required to create an output data.

But it seems `Spark` does not start to process a `RDD` in a `DStream` until the previous `RDD` finishes even when the previous `RDD` uses only a few partitions and CPU/memory.

Is it `Spark`'s default behaviour ? Is there any way to change such behaviour ?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/monitoring.html#web-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Can you kindly post your code and the problem you are facing?

Conceptually, data within each time interval forms a rdd at the end of the interval (thats the idea of forming a mini-batch data abstraction).

Comment: Please post these requests for clarifications as comments.